# Why SteamOverly Pause Not Working In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, steamworks-api

I am Developing a game In Unity for Steam. And I am using SteamWorks.net Package for that in unity. My achievement System is working fine with that But the pause game on SteamOverly is not working. I am trying to run the from Unity Editor. I there any way I can test this from unity Editor.
 I am using the following code for that

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Steamworks;

public class SteamScript : MonoBehaviour {
    protected Callback<GameOverlayActivated_t> m_GameOverlayActivated;

    private void OnEnable() {
        if (SteamManager.Initialized) { //This working
            Debug.Log("INIT");
            m_GameOverlayActivated = Callback<GameOverlayActivated_t>.Create(OnGameOverlayActivated);
        }
    }

    private void OnGameOverlayActivated(GameOverlayActivated_t pCallback) {

           Debug.Log("Entered"); //This is not workinfdg

           // this is not calling
        if(pCallback.m_bActive != 0) {
            Debug.Log("Steam Overlay has been activated");
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("Steam Overlay has been closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint and tried debugging ?

Comment: No Hoto do that in unity... and i am using visual studio code

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) != C#

Comment: Also see this bug on the steamworks page about why callbacks may not be working: https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET/issues/227

Comment: This code does work, but only for the Steam button not quick settings.

Answer (score 0):

The steam overlay does not work in the editor, you will need to make a build. See documentation here: https://steamworks.github.io/faq/#can-steamworksnet-be-used-within-the-unity-editor